# Projecting database with same table for other tables

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new with databases.

I have two tables:

- banks
- exchangers

Each of these tables could have one or more telephone numbers. For example bank A could have two phones, and exchanger B could have 5 telephone numbers.

I could do this: for banks, create linked table `bank_phones` and do so also for exchanger. But then I will have two tables with almost the same structure. Is this okay, or can I do it better?

I think about something like: table phone with fields id, main_id (link for other tables, as bank or exchanger), type (will write here bank or exchanger), phone_number). Is this a good idea? If not, how can I do it better?

Comment: In general I would have two separate tables for telephone numbers, especially if you can use a MySQL table type that supports foreign keys; you can ensure you have referential integrity only if each telephone table can have a key pointing to the entity it belongs to.

Comment: @halfer as an answer please.... and more detaily and easier.... little problems with english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, I would do it the long way. That is to say I'd have tables called `bank_phone` and `exchanger_phone`. This means that, if you are willing to use the `InnoDB` table type in MySQL, you can use `FOREIGN KEY` references to ensure telephone numbers can only be attached to banks and exchanges that actually exist ([see more here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)).

Equally, this will prevent a bank or exchanger being deleted if telephone numbers exist for them, which is generally a good thing. This is called *referential integrity* and helps keep references between tables in good order.